# If $f$ is invertible and additive, Show that $f^{-1}$ is also additive

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-writing

$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$
is the definition of additive function. I am given that $f$ is invertible and show that $f^{-1}$ is also additive.

My answer so far is that

For $ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists a \in X, \exists b \in Y,$ such that
$f^{-1}(a) = x, f^{-1}(b) = y $
And since we know that $f$ is invertible and additive, 
$f(x) + f(y) = a+b$

we prove that

$f^{-1}(a+b) = f^{-1}(a) + f^{-1}(b) $

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes, I think you are missing the crucial step: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. And this implies what exactly? You may say that you use the additivity, but you don’t actually say how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incomplete.

1. You didn't explain how you know that $f(x)+f(y)=a+b$.
2. You didn't explain how $f^{-1}(a+b)=f^{-1}(a) + f^{-1}(b)$ follows from $f(x)+f(y)=a+b$
3. Since you started with $x,y\in\mathbb R$, you need to prove $f^{-1}(x+y)=f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(y)$, not the equality with $a,b$.

Comment: I think I’d be lenient with point one …

Comment: @k.stm If point 1 were the only mistake, I'd let it go. But in my experience, when grading papers, often when I asked a student "how do you know this?" about very simple equalities, it turned out they didn't know how to prove them. This was more true for students writing very confused proofs (like this one OP provided).

Comment: Okay, point taken. (But it’s not a *mistake*.)

Comment: @k.stm Well, I didn't say the proof has a mistake. I just said it's incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(y)$ then $f(a)=f(f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(y))=f(f^{-1}(x)) + f(f^{-1}(y))=x + y=f(f^{-1}(x+y))$. Now using $f$ invective, we have $a=f^{-1}(x+y)$